# Making y the subject of equation while maintaining the domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

Because I am plotting the curve on a graphing calculator, I have to change the subject of the following equation to y.

> x=0.07(y+3)^2-4.7

I got:

> y=((x+4.7)/0.07)^0.5-3

But now the line is cut off because y≥-3. I can't get the same line! :( Is it even possible? Thanks a bunch for your help! :)

Comment: Take care. You solve $y^2=a$. So, you have two branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manipulation seems fine, but we lost solutions by retaining only the positive square root of both sides of $$(x-4.7)/0.07=(y+3)^2.$$  We need to use two functions together to account for all solutions.  We include both $$\sqrt{(x+4.7)/0.07}=y+3 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sqrt{(x+4.7)/0.07}=-(y+3)$$ which simplify to $$y=\sqrt{(x+4.7)/0.07}-3 \qquad\text{and}\qquad y=-\sqrt{(x+4.7)/0.07}-3.$$